# .NET String performance question

Tags: c#, .net, performance, string

Is it better, from a performance standpoint, to use "Example1"?  I'm assuming that "Example2" would create a new string on the heap in each iteration while "Example1" would not...

Example1:

```
StringBuilder letsCount = new StringBuilder("Let's count! ");
string sep = ", ";
for(int i=; i< 100; i++)
{
     letsCount.Append(i + sep);
}
```

Example2:

```
StringBuilder letsCount = new StringBuilder("Let's count! ");
for(int i=; i< 100; i++)
{
     letsCount.Append(i + ", ");
}
```

Comment: +1 For exposing me to a usage of StringBuilder I've never seen before ... automatic conversion of internal non-string parameters to strings (if that's the right way to describe it) ... (and that doesn't apear documented in MSDN).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The .NET CLR is much smarter than that. It "[interns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx)" string literals so that there is only one instance.

It's also worth noting that if you were truly concerned about string concatenation, you would want to turn the single Append call into two append calls. The reality, however, is that the overhead of two calls probably outweighs any minor concatenation cost. In either case, it's probably nearly immeasurable except in very controlled conditions.

Comment: I think you should try out, using a stopwatch, it is very well measurable, that using a stringbuilder is faster already at more than 4-5 concatenations.

Comment: I am well aware of the benefits of using a stringbuilder for multiple concatenations. I was referring to the difference between Append(i+sep) and Append(i); Append(sep); x 100.

Comment: I did take your advice though and time it. x100 - 0ms (72 ticks) vs 0ms (61 ticks), x100000 - 32ms (71,517 ticks) vs 26ms (58,870 ticks)

Comment: +1 This interesting analysis leaves me wondering about the "internal cost" of the (apparently) automatic conversion of the loop index variable from int to "whatever" (so it can be concatenated with the SB). Also raises the interesting question, for me, of under what circumstances (if any) "chained" appends like : "s1.Append(i).Append(s2);" would have a "payoff." thanks,

Answer (score 2):

They are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a much faster way to do it would be

```
string letsCount = "Let's count! ";
string[] numbers = new string[100];
for(int i=0; i< 100; i++)
{ 
   numbers[i]=i+", ";
}
String.Join(letsCount, numbers);
```

[See here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/StringBuilder_vs_String.aspx)

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the link.  I'll have to remember that in the future.  I'd be curious to see that graph after there were 100 concatenated strings...